# how to read the WHOLE char type captured data using Boost.Asio

Tags: c++, type-conversion, boost-asio

I have come accros with a funny moment when working with boost::asio. The problem is that i wanted to make a voice chat and used OpenAL where i keep the captured data in ALubyte:

```
ALubyte* data; // data has the captured data now
int data_size;
```

so i send data converting it to char*

```
boost::asio::streambuf m_buf;
std::ostream out(&m_buf);
out << data_size << ';'; // the simbol ';' is used to separate data from each other  
out.write((char*)data, data_size);
out << 'q'; // the simbol 'q' is used for a client side to understand that 
            //this is the end of the stream 
            // as a client where the 'out' stream is sent to, 
            //uses boost::async_read_until --> ooops

boost::asio::async_write(client_sock, m_buf, [](){});
```

as you might have already guessed, the problem is in boost::asio::async_read_until

```
//in a client side

boost::asio::streambuf client_buf;
std::istream in(&client_buf);

boost::asio::async_read_until(m_sock, client_buf, 'q', [](){});//---> oooops,   
        // this boost::asio::async_read_until 
        //function reads until the first 'q' simbol which  'data' might 
        //have a lot of 'q' simbol as the captured data is stored as
        // a char type
        //so the function does not read the whole captured data.
```

Guys i do know this is my OWN big mistake to choose this function, but i can`t change it NOW as the code is a bit large 
so do you have some idea what to do in this case so that i could read the whole captured data, or do you think there is no way 
out without changing boost::asio::async_read_until function? any idea is highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Aren't you already passing the data size as the header of the message? Can't you just read sizeof(data_size) bytes, and then make a second read of that + 2 (for the ; and the q)?

Comment: Just choose a better delimiter or use the size that you send up front

Answer (score 0):

istead of the simbol 'q', a better choice would be adding more simbols like "cpp"
and in this case the data that keeps the captured in a char type might not have exaclty the same signature, 'q' simbols may be a lot in data but using "cpp"... etc will risk less than only one 'q' simbol, which mean the more added simbols the less risk!